# Почему так криво отображается leaflet карта?

Tags: vue.js, openstreetmap, leafletjs

[image: Карта]

код vue.js компонента

```js
<template>
    <div id="map">
        <div id="leaflet-map" class="leaflet-map"></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "MapComponent",

        created() {
            window._map = this;
        },

        mounted() {
            let map = L.map('leaflet-map');

            var osmUrl='https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
            var osmAttrib='';

            var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 8, maxZoom: 12, attribution: osmAttrib})

            map.setView(new L.LatLng(51.3, 0.7),9);
            map.addLayer(osm);
        },

    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По все видимости Вы забыли подключить `leaflet.css`

---

Рабочий вариант (c подключенной `css`):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<style>
  body, #map {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script>
  new L.Map('map', {
      center: new L.LatLng(60, 30.3), 
      zoom: 12,
      layers: [new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')]
  });
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Вариант с проблемой похожий на Вашу (без подключенной `css`) :

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.4.0/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<style>
  body, #map {
      margin: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script>
  new L.Map('map', {
      center: new L.LatLng(60, 30.3), 
      zoom: 12,
      layers: [new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')]
  });
</script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Разница в том что во втором варианте css не подключен?

Comment: @Arseniys в точку